# How can I get the Hedera JS SDK to shut down gracefully?

Tags: javascript, hedera-hashgraph

I am using [hedera-sdk-js](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-sdk-js),
version 2.37.0, installed from `@hashgraph/sdk` on NPM.
​

When I run a script in NodeJs, the process remains open indefinitely,
and in order to force it to terminate,
I have been using `process.exit(0);`.
This works, but is not ideal - I would prefer that it terminates gracefully.
​

Is there a way to do this?
​

---

​

Details:

Here is the current script
​

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {
    Client,
    AccountId,
    PrivateKey,
} from '@hashgraph/sdk';
​
dotenv.config();
main();
​
async function main() {
    if (!process.env.ACCOUNT_ID ||
        !process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY) {
        throw new Error('Please set required keys in .env file.');
    }
​
    const accountId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.ACCOUNT_ID);
    const accountKey = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(accountId, accountKey);
​
    // ... do some things here ...
​
    process.exit(0); // <-- NOTE would like to remove this
}
​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Client` instance is keeping the Javascript event loop open.
For a graceful shutdown of your script,
you simply need to stop the `Client` instance, using `.close()`.

Here's the modified version of your code example,
only one line has changed:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {
    Client,
    AccountId,
    PrivateKey,
} from '@hashgraph/sdk';

dotenv.config();
main();

async function main() {
    if (!process.env.ACCOUNT_ID ||
        !process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY) {
        throw new Error('Please set required keys in .env file.');
    }

    const accountId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.ACCOUNT_ID);
    const accountKey = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA(process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY);
    const client = Client.forTestnet().setOperator(accountId, accountKey);

    // ... do some things here ...

    client.close() // Replaced process.exit with client.close
}
```